# Getting exception while getting token with ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientID) using MSAL

Tags: c#, azure, .net-6.0, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to get the access token by following code but getting exception at **AcquireTokenForClient**.

Here is the code:

```
        var clientID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        var clientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

        var authority = "https://<your-tenant>.b2clogin.com/<your-tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/<your-policyID>";


        var clientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientID)
          .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
          .WithAuthority(authority)
          .Build();


        var scopes = new string[] { "{resourceId}/.default" };

        var authenticationResult = await clientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
          .ExecuteAsync()
          .ConfigureAwait(false);

        var accesstoken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
```

here is the exception:

```
    Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (AADSTS50049: Unknown or invalid instance.
 ---> MSAL.CoreCLR.4.59.0.0.MsalServiceException:
        ErrorCode: invalid_instance
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: AADSTS50049: Unknown or invalid instance. 
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.ThrowServerException(HttpResponse response, RequestContext requestContext)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.CreateResponse[T](HttpResponse response, RequestContext requestContext)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.ExecuteRequestAsync[T](Uri endPoint, HttpMethod method, RequestContext requestContext, Boolean expectErrorsOn200OK, Boolean addCommonHeaders, Func`2 onBeforePostRequestData)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.DiscoverAadInstanceAsync(Uri endpoint, RequestContext requestContext)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Instance.Discovery.NetworkMetadataProvider.SendInstanceDiscoveryRequestAsync(Uri authority, RequestContext requestContext)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Instance.Discovery.NetworkMetadataProvider.FetchAllDiscoveryMetadataAsync(Uri authority, RequestContext requestContext)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Instance.Discovery.NetworkMetadataProvider.GetMetadataAsync(Uri authority, RequestContext requestContext)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Instance.Discovery.InstanceDiscoveryManager.FetchNetworkMetadataOrFallbackAsync(RequestContext requestContext, Uri authorityUri)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Instance.Discovery.InstanceDiscoveryManager.GetMetadataEntryAsync(AuthorityInfo authorityInfo, RequestContext requestContext, Boolean forceValidation)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Instance.AuthorityManager.RunInstanceDiscoveryAndValidationAsync()
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ClientCredentialRequest.GetAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, ILoggerAdapter logger)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ClientCredentialRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.ConfidentialClientExecutor.ExecuteAsync(AcquireTokenCommonParameters commonParameters, AcquireTokenForClientParameters clientParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I registered one Azure AD B2C application and added **API permissions** as below:

[image]

When I tried to acquire access token using your code, I too got **same error** as below:

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var clientId = "appId";
        var clientSecret = "secret";
        var authority = "https://b2ctenant.b2clogin.com/b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SUSI";

        var clientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(authority)
            .Build();

        var scopes = new string[] { "https://b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/API_appId/.default" };

        try
        {
            var authenticationResult = await clientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

            var accessToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

            Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {accessToken}");
        }
        catch (MsalServiceException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error acquiring token: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make use of below *modified* code by changing B2C authority that generates **access token** like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var clientId = "appId";
        var clientSecret = "secret";
        var tenant = "b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com";
        var policyId = "B2C_1_SUSI";

        var authority = $"https://b2ctenant.b2clogin.com/tfp/{tenant}/{policyId}";

        var clientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithB2CAuthority(authority.ToString())  
            .WithTenantId(tenant)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .Build();

        var scopes = new string[] { $"https://b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/API_appId/.default" };

        try
        {
            var authenticationResult = await clientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

            var accessToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

            Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {accessToken}");
        }
        catch (MsalServiceException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error acquiring token: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I decoded the above token in [**jwt.ms**](https://jwt.ms) website and got below claims:

[image]